# How can we call a substory within a jbehave story that does not create a new browser instance?

Tags: jbehave

I wish to load a sub story within a story of jbehave , which should not create a new browser session , just like GivenStories syntax but not as a pre-condition

Scenario: Main Story

Given I login

Then I load another story by providing story path (execution runs on the same browser)

We have developed a custom framework on top of jbehave which is compiled into an executable jar file using maven.
Story path is provided in a .properties file which is loaded and parsed by the executable jar . Using the properties file , a new browser is instantiated in the constructor of a class every time a story is executed

I wish that I load a story in between a story and the execution keeps running on the same browser

Comment: please provide more details: how do you instantiate browser sessions? are you using any frameworks on top of JBehave?

Comment: Hi @VaL Yes we have developed a custom framework on top of jbehave which is compiled into an executable jar file using maven. Story path is provided in a .properties file which is loaded and parsed by the executable jar

Comment: So in this case you fully manage browser session state and can decide when new session should be created and when it shouldn't. If you are you looking for a particular advice, you should post your implementation of browser management implementation

Comment: Okay , Thanks for the suggestion @VaL. I'm not sure if I could post the code due to privacy policies.
Still, Thanks